# linq to sql -> join

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

SQL query:

```
SELECT     ArticleCategories.Title AS Category, Articles.Title, Articles.[Content], Articles.Date
FROM         ArticleCategories INNER JOIN
                   Articles ON ArticleCategories.CategoryID = Articles.CategoryID
```

Object repository:

```
public class ArticleDisplay
    {
        public int CategoryID;
        public string CategoryTitle;

        public int ArticleID;
        public string ArticleTitle;
        //public string ArticleDate;
        public string ArticleContent;
    }    


public class ArticleRepository
    {
        private DB db = new DB();
        //
        // Query Methods
        public IQueryable<ArticleDisplay> FindAllArticles()
        {
            var result =   from category in db.ArticleCategories
                           join article in db.Articles on category.CategoryID equals article.CategoryID
                           select new
                           {
                               CategoryID = category.CategoryID,
                               CategoryTitle = category.Title,

                               ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
                               ArticleTitle = article.Title,
                               //ArticleDate = article.Date,
                               ArticleContent = article.Content
                           };

            return result;

        }
        ....
    }
```

And finally, I get this error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ilija\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\CMS\CMS\Models\ArticleRepository.cs 29  20  CMS

Any idea what did I do wrong?

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method has a return type of IQueryable<Article>, but your LINQ query is not returning articles.  Instead it's trying to return an anonymous type made up of properties from both category and article.  You could create a class to hold this combination of properties and change the method signature to use that class.

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly should I make this new class? I'm pretty new to C# so I'm having big troubles with this one...
This is what I tried:

public class ArticleDisplay
    {
        public string CategoryID;
        public string CategoryTitle;

        public string ArticleID;
        public string ArticleTitle;
        public string ArticleDate;
        public string ArticleContent;
    }

Comment: You need to match the data types (are they really all string?) but, yes, a simple class like that would do.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam said, if you're not wanting to return the full article class then you'll need to return your own class.

```
public IQueryable<ArticleDisplay> FindAllArticles()
    {
        var result =   from category in db.ArticleCategories
                       join article in db.Articles on category.CategoryID equals article.CategoryID
                       select new ArticleDisplay() //specify your new class
                       {
                           CategoryID = category.CategoryID,
                           CategoryTitle = category.Title,
                           ....
                       };

        return result;

    }
```

Your updated code still returns an anonymous class....

Comment: Yap, I forgot to add ArticleDisplay() after "select new"... thanks!